# Crear una Consulta SQL con los campos nombre de cliente, nombre de producto y total de compra de productos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo este problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy creando una consulta sql, en la imagen está el ejercicio, ya tengo casi todo pero no logro contar o sumar todas las compras que ha hecho el cliente

Mi query es este:

```
SELECT 
clientes.nombre AS 'Clientes', productos.nombre AS 'Productos', 
venta_detalle.cantidad AS 'Total comprado' 
FROM clientes 
INNER JOIN productos ON clientes.codigo = productos.codigo 
INNER JOIN venta_detalle ON productos.codigo = venta_detalle.codigo 
WHERE 
venta_detalle.cantidad > 200 
ORDER BY venta_detalle.cantidad DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega por favor tu consulta en formato de texto

Comment: SELECT clientes.nombre AS 'Clientes', productos.nombre AS 'Productos', venta_detalle.cantidad AS 'Total comprado' FROM clientes INNER JOIN productos ON clientes.codigo = productos.codigo INNER JOIN venta_detalle ON productos.codigo = venta_detalle.codigo WHERE venta_detalle.cantidad > 200 ORDER BY venta_detalle.cantidad DESC // esa me muestra los campos que me pide pero no logro sumar todas las compras que hacen los clientes pero que me de uno por uno total

Comment: Puedes usar GROUP BY para agrupar por cliente y SUM para sumar los montos de compra.

Answer (score 2):

Ese total que muestras es relativo pues no está sumando la cantidad de cada cliente entonces en tu Select agrega

```
SUM(venta_detalle.cantidad)
```

Posterior agrupa por las columnas de tu Select menos la que se calcula con la función de agregación así

```
 GROUP BY clientes.nombre, productos.nombre
```

La sentencia de agrupamiento escribe la entre tú WHERE y tú order by

Considera que si no se puedan agrupar los nombres de los productos por ser únicos entonces deberás agrupar todos los productos que le pertenecen a ese cliente así

```
GROUP_CONCAT(productos.nombre)
```

Lo anterior lo pones en tu Select en lugar de solo invocar la columna nombre de la tabla productos